# Firefox temporary folder (not cache)

Tags: firefox, downloads

I would like to download big file (over 5 GB) from MyAirBridge.com as free user. This service requires to click on link, then it "prepares download" for several hours but ability to save it on local disk is displayed as standard Firefox downloader window *after* the file is stored on temporary folder. Because of file size I got message that my temporary folder is to small (out of space) but... after downloading almost all file. I suppose it is downloaded to /tmp.

How can I change default folder of temporary files (not cache!) in about:config or other config files of my Firefox installation?

I'm using Kubuntu 17.10, Firefox 59.

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed at length in this Firefox bug report (warning: it dates back 14 years!)

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69938

If you have it set so Firefox asks you for a save location, or if the download would trigger a dialog asking you what to do, then it will pop up a dialog asking you where to save.  But it will *begin downloading* even before you have chosen a save location.  This download will go into your temp folder.  Once you choose a save location, Firefox moves the file from the temp folder to the chosen location and then the download continues at that location instead of in your temp folder.

Your issue seems to be that you miss the dialog coming up because you're not present, and it tries to download the whole thing into the temp folder and fails because there's not enough space.

You can try changing your Firefox settings so it doesn't prompt you for a save location and instead goes into a downloads folder of your choice and this *may* fix it.

Comment: Thank you for deep search! It's a lot of discussion and possible solutions. I will try them!